# Build field extension and solve equation

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, roots

Build quadratic extension of field that contains $5$ elements. And solve $x^2+x+2=0$ in this field.

As I understand we need to build $\mathbb{F}_{5^{2}}$.

Field $\mathbb{F}_5$ contains $\{0,1,2,3,4\}.$

And as I understand field $\mathbb{F}_{5^{2}}$ contains $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and polynomials $\{x+1,x+2,x+3,x+4,2x+, \cdots, 4x+4\}$. $20$ polynomials $ax+b$, where $a,b \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$. Totally we have $25$ objects in this field.

And I have no idea how to solve equation. Maybe we can try every element, but this is too difficult and here must be simpler way.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Find something interesting: if we let $t$ be the root of $x^2+x+2=0$ than $4t+4$ will be the root too! We get that $t^2+t+2=0$. If we put $x=4t+4$ than get: $(4t+4)^2+4t+4+2=16t^2+36t+22(mod5)=t^2+t+2=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest description of the  quadratic extension is that it has the same $25$ elements as yours, with addition defined in the obvious way, and  $x^2$ being defined as $-x-2$, that is, $4x+3$. Then $x$ is a solution of your quadratic equation.

Once we have defined $x^2$, the product $ax+b)(cx+d)$ can be defined in the "natural" way: Multiply as usual, and replace $x^2$ by $4x+3$.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the trick in André's answer (+1) would be to use the usual quadratic formula. That works over any field where you can *complete the square*, which is the case whenever you can divide by two. This in turn is always possible, when $2\neq0$, i.e. when the characteristic is not equal to two.

Here we get that $x^2+x+2=0$, iff
$$
x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1^2-4\cdot2}}2=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{-7}}2.
$$
In order to use this we need to make sense of that $\sqrt{-7}$. In $\Bbb{F}_5$ we have $-7=3$ as $-7\equiv3\pmod5$. Thus we need to locate something that we can call $\sqrt3$. Quick testing reveals that no element $a\in\Bbb{F}_5$ satisfies the equation $a^2=3$, so we need to extend the field.

The way to introduce $\sqrt3$ is the usual. For the given reason $x^2-3$ is irreducible, and thus $\Bbb{F}_5[x]/\langle x^2-3\rangle$ is a field with 25 elements. It has the element $\alpha=x+\langle x^2-3\rangle$ that satisfies $\alpha^2=3$. So in the field $\Bbb{F}_{25}=\Bbb{F}_5[\alpha]$ the original equation has the solutions $(-1\pm\alpha)/2=2\pm3\alpha$. The last step follows from the fact that $2\cdot3=6=1\in\Bbb{F}_5$, so $3=\frac12$ here.

The field $\Bbb{F}[\alpha]$ is, of course, isomorphic to the field André used. After all, there is only one field of 25 elements up to isomorphism. An explicit isomorphism can be given by mapping his (coset of) $x$ to what I called $2\pm3\alpha$. Either sign works.

Note that by creating $\sqrt3$ we also created $\sqrt2$. This is because in all extension fields of $\Bbb{F}_5$ containing a $\sqrt3$
$$
2=12=4\cdot3=2^2\cdot3,
$$
so
$$
\sqrt2=\sqrt{2^2\cdot3}=\pm2\sqrt3.
$$
Thus $\pm2\alpha$ serve in the role of square roots of two in the field $\Bbb{F}_5[\alpha]$. This is yet another manifestation of the fact that there is (up to isomorphism) only one field of 25 elements.